# PetaPoco doesn't return results when ordering by NEWID()

Tags: c#, wcf, petapoco

I'm using the brilliant PetaPoco as my ORM for a small WCF service. I have a small method that gets 5 random records from SQL:

```
public IEnumerable<Stock> GetRandomStock(int number)
{
        Database db = new Database("MyCS");
        var sql = Sql.Builder.Append("SELECT TOP @0 * FROM Stock ORDER BY NEWID()", number);
        var results = db.Query<Stock>(sql);

        return results;
}
```

If I run the query in Management Studio, I get the correct number of results based on my parameter. when debugging, I can also see that my parameter is being passed to the query.

Any ideas why I don't get any results?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you iterating over the results? If not then the query will not run.

You should use `Fetch` instead `Query` as `Query` runs the query only when you start iterating over the results.

```
public IEnumerable<Stock> GetRandomStock(int number)
{
        Database db = new Database("MyCS");
        var sql = "SELECT TOP @0 * FROM Stock ORDER BY NEWID()";
        var results = db.Fetch<Stock>(sql, number);

        return results;
}
```